# Concrete5 Add-Block panel opens when page placed in edit mode

Tags: javascript, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

With Concrete5 8.1, when I put the page in edit mode by clicking the button with tool tip "Edit this Page" (pencil icon), the page reloads and then the button with the "+" icon appears to have a click event, opening the Add Blocks panel.

I tried to write that as simple as possible so it's clear what is happening.  To be more technical, it appears that when the page reloads in edit mode, there is a click event called for the button that opens the blocks panel.  This panel shouldn't open unless I explicitly click the button to do so.  The edit button should only put the page in edit mode, allowing me to select existing blocks.

Once the blocks panel is opened, I can click the edit button again and the blocks panel will close, leaving the page in edit mode.  However, that second click should actually cause the page to exit edit mode.

Has someone else had a similar problem, and is there a fix for it?

Thanks

Comment: There is an issue for this in git you can check out https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/issues/5193

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer, but it's not a fix.
The concrete5 dev team confirms it's a problem in 8.1 when C5 is running from a subfolder rather than the root of the web site, e.g (as described in the issue report referenced above) as http://mycompany.com/directory rather than http://mycompany.com.

So, one potential fix is to reconfigure your website to run as the top-level site in your domain.

If that's not possible, you could patch the file CookieMiddleware.php as described in the issue description (2 lines, simple fix).

Or you could wait for the next point release (8.2).  No indication from the dev team when that might be.